# Umbraco media sharing - Development

Tags: umbraco7

been struggling with setting up Umbraco on a development machine and test server...

Both environments connect to the same database and I use uSync to keep all my changes in git, however mediafiles are a real p.i.t.a.

I started off by adding media on my dev machine and copying over the media folder when publishing to test. Not very elegant so I tried using the rootPath and rootUrl in the filesystemproviders config. Path points to a network file share and URL to a dedicated virtual directory hosted on a media.test.mysite.com subdomain.

Surprise ... when opening the site the old media is vanished because umbraco saves the absolute path in the cmsProperty tables {'src': 'http://media.mysite.com/1041/...' }, previously the relative path when configuring the virtualRoot.

I'd like to alter the composition of the media url's in both front-and backend. Define a media_root appsetting holding the hostname, protocol and port (http://media.test.mysite.com) and prepending this to the src stuff that comes from the DB...

Any suggestions?
I already tried a custom URLProvider but this only works for non-media content ... it seems :-|

Thanks!
Y.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [Umbraco File System Provider for Azure](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure) which will upload your media to Azure Blob Storage.  You can then use the disk cache that comes with ImageProcessor.Web (included in Umbraco Core) to cache the files locally.  We run our dev environments pointing to the same blob storage as other environments - so no need to copy the files.  And the references are relative (/media/1001/file.jpg) when using Disk Cache thanks to the HTTP module in [ImageProcessor.Web](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/) which caches them to disk. (You could alternatively use the [ImageProcessor Azure blob cache plugin](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/plugins/azure-blob-cache/) and have the images load from Azure.  You might want to check out [this documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Set-Up/Media/) at Our.Umbraco.org (even if you aren't using Umbraco Cloud).